Why only trap states near the intrinsic Fermi level are considered in the Shockley-Read-Hall recombination theory?
Most of the solid state device textbooks (UG level) that I went through considers trap states at the intrinsic Fermi energy while applying the Shockley-Read-Hall (SRH) theory. It is stated that these traps are 'more significant'.
Is there any good reasoning behind this approximation? I have plotted the recombination rate using SRH and found the rate to be almost flat for around 0.8 eV at 300 K, which is close the the total band gap of silicon. So, any trap states within silicon band gap should be equally effective. In that case, why do we consider trap states around the intrinsic Fermi level only?


It simplifies the derivation somewhat. "Trap" states near band edges are also known as "dopant" levels, so don't tend to be occupied by one charge or the other for very long since they will thermalize back out readily, in contrast to mid-gap states.
